Error: Code=InvalidTemplateDeployment; Message=The template deployment 'StAccDeployment' is not valid according to the validation procedure
PowerShell Command:
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name 'StAccDeployment' -TemplateFile '.\CreateStorageAccount.bicep' -ResourceGroupName 'bicepworks' -Mode Incremental

CreateStorageAccount.bicep:
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-05-01' = {
  name: 'rajstaccprc01'
  location: 'centralindia'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'BlobStorage'
}


The above bicep template is a basic one. When I see some udemy course video, the tutor succeeded the provisioning of the storage account using above basic template.
I know the video is from long ago. So, Do I miss any parameters in the above bicep code.
Correct me where I missed the code:
Error details:
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 15:25:52 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplateDeployment; Message=The template deployment 'StAccDeployment' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'fb97bd7c-328a5a3c995b'. See inner errors for details.
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 15:25:52 - Error: Code=PreflightValidationCheckFailed; Message=Preflight validation failed. Please refer to the details for the specific errors.
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 15:25:52 - Error: Code=MissingRequiredAccountProperty; Message=Account property accessTier is required for the request.
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: The deployment validation failed


As @jitter answered, if using kind = BlobStorage, the accessTier in properties is required. reference
resource storageAccount1 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-05-01' = {
  name: 'satest111'
  location: 'westus'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'BlobStorage'
  properties: {
    accessTier: 'Cold'
  }
}



Try to use kind = 'StorageV2' to make it easy if the kind not mandatory, v2 type is also recommanded.
resource storageAccount2 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-05-01' = {
  name: 'satest222'
  location: 'westus'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}

here is a sample reference

The error message says it all

Code=MissingRequiredAccountProperty; Message=Account property accessTier is required

Also the relevant MS docs for Microsoft.Storage storageAccounts 2023-05-01 state

accessTier: Required for storage accounts where kind = BlobStorage.

Valid values are below. You can read about & choose the appropriate tier on the Access tiers for blob data docs page
- Cold
- Cool
- Hot
- Premium

So adding something like this should do it
properties: {
    accessTier: 'Hot'
}

